# How to delete remotes/origin/{branch}?

Tags: git

How do you delete a remotes/origin/{branch}?

Answer (score 63):

use: `git remote prune origin`

or use `git remote prune origin --dry-run` to preview what branches will be removed.

As in `git help remote`

**prune**
Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under . These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by , but are still locally available in "remotes/".

With --dry-run option, report what branches will be pruned, but do not actually prune them.

Comment: What's about if the remote branch still exists and I want to eliminate the remotes/origin/{branch}? I have an issue with that because there are two remote branches named **API_v2** and **API_V2**, same name except by the "v" or "V" letter. The local repository is windows and it is case insensitive, both branches target the same remotes/origin/{branch} I guess.

Answer (score 11):

Let's say you've fetched a branch like so:

```
git fetch origin MT-2766
```

To remove the corresponding remote-tracking branch run:

```
git branch -r -d origin/MT-2766
```

Comment: Or `$ git branch --list -r | grep -v HEAD | xargs git branch -r -d` for deletion of all remote-tracking branches.

Answer (score 3):

`git push origin :[branch-name]`.

Source: http://progit.org/book/ch3-5.html

Comment: for deleting tracking branches use "git remote prune origin" when you delete branch from origin

Comment: this will delete [branch-name] on remote git server but not the local `remotes/origin/[branch-name]`

Answer (score 3):

`git branch -r -d origin/branch-name` worked for me when the remote branch was already deleted (so `git push origin --delete <branch-name>` wasn't possible) and `git prune origin` wasn't doing anything (for a reason I don't yet understand)

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me