# How do I remove deleted branch names from autocomplete?

Tags: git

I used `git branch -d myBranch` to delete a branch. However, when I am on master and try to checkout a new branch with `git checkout`, `myBranch` still appears in the tab-autocomplete.

How do I remove the name `myBranch` from tab-autocomplete for `git checkout`?

Comment: Does `git branch -a` still list either `myBranch` or `origin/myBranch`? Note that, even if `myBranch` doesn't exist, `git checkout myBranch` is still a valid shortcut for `git checkout -b myBranch origin/myBranch` if `origin/myBranch` exists.

Comment: @twalberg worth posting as an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66224972/603653 has the answer for deleting just a single remote branch ```git branch -r -d origin/myBranch``` (for me it was remotes/origins/myBranch, use whatever git branch -a shows)- and then that stopped autocompleting

Answer (score 120, accepted):

One possible reason for this is that, if a remote branch (e.g. `origin/myBranch`) still exists, then `git checkout myBranch` will succeed as an alternative to `git checkout -b myBranch origin/myBranch`. This is intended as a convenience for the common case of checkout out a remote branch for the first time, creating an identically named local tracking branch.

There are other possibilities, too, depending on what exactly you are using for completion, but that's one of the first things I'd check. If you run `git branch -a`, and there is an `origin/myBranch` listed (or one for a remote other than `origin`, if you have such), then that's a likely culprit.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the culprit. `origin/myBranch` still exists. If I deleted the `myBranch` branch on Github (through the online interface), is it safe for me to call `git branch -d origin/myBranch` to remove that remote branch?

Comment: @JohnHoffman That should be safe, but I think the better way would be `git fetch --prune origin`. That will clean up all local tracking branches that no longer exist on the remote.

Comment: @twalberg I don't believe simply deleting the local and remote branch is enough to get rid of all of the old branches in autocomplete. I believe you _need_ to `git fetch --prune origin` for the local references to remote branches to go away in autocomplete. Might be good to move that from the comment to the answer. In any case thanks for your response as it helped me!

Comment: `git branch -a` led me on the right track; my coworker suggested `git fetch --prune --all` to prune all the dead branches from all the remotes, which is useful when working with lots of devs with lots of forks.

Answer (score 278):

`git fetch --prune --all`

Posting this as its own answer since it's a one-line fix, but if you vote be sure to vote for [twalberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17935627/866022).

twalberg's suggestion to `git branch -a` led me on the right track; my coworker suggested `git fetch --prune --all` to prune all the dead branches from all the remotes, which is useful when working with lots of devs with lots of forks.

Comment: While the accepted answer gives a nice explanation why this happens, this answer presents an actual solution to the problem and should therefore be accepted IMHO.

Comment: dead branches names are still showing in autocomplete.

Comment: Reminder: delete the obsolete branches on the remote first (Github)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your setup, there is another source of what might look like old or deleted branches - your git-completion may also be suggesting *tags* along with branches.

I was fooled by this recently - our CI/CD pipeline tags all our builds, and even though certain branches would be released and/or deleted years ago, the tags persisted. Cleaning up old tags on the remote was the solution here ([there is a guide here](https://devconnected.com/how-to-delete-local-and-remote-tags-on-git/)).

(I answered this [here as well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688177/430455) - not sure if it counts as a duplicate as it's on StackExchange...?)