# Delete unlisted branch in Git repo

Tags: git, branch

I have an auto complete script that allows me to type:

```
git checkout m
```

then hit the 'tab' button and it will autocomplete. In this case, it should autocomplete to 'master'.

However, my script is telling me I have two other branches in my repo titled:

- making-test-branch
- mess-up

I have tried to delete them using a force delete like so:

```
git branch -D making-test-branch
```

However, I get the following error saying the branch was not found:

```
error: branch 'making-test-branch' not found.
```

And when I list all my local branches with 'git branch', the branches are not listed.

What am I missing here that I cannot delete these two branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check out this similar issue and see if it answers your question:
[How do I remove deleted branch names from autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933401/how-do-i-remove-deleted-branch-names-from-autocomplete)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even realize that was the actual problem to search for it like that. The solution on the other question fixed my problem. I will accept your answer as soon as SO allows me.