# How to delete a git remote that no longer exists

Tags: git

I am trying to do some remedial git clean-up work on a repository that was started a while back. When I run `git branch -a` I get the following output:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
staging
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/staging
remotes/pythonanywhere/master
remotes/pythonanywhere/staging
remotes/staging/staging
```

The `remotes/staging/staging` remote does not exist anymore. It does not show up in the list when running `git remote -v`.

This also seems to mean I cannot delete the remote.

`get fetch -p`, `git remote prune staging` also do not work.

Also the remote does not show up in the list of remotes when running `git config --local -l`

## EDIT:

The suggested possible duplicate questions/answers did not work when trying to solve this issue. For some reason the remote was left as an orphan. See the accepted answer below for what worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete remotes/origin/{branch}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703200/how-to-delete-remotes-origin-branch)

Comment: Check the accepted answer for [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/5395709)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove local branches no longer on remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-local-branches-no-longer-on-remote)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to these other answers. I perused them all before deciding to ask my own version.

Each of those answers contained steps that I tried first, but did not work. Thus the new question, which was just answered in the comments below.

Comment: If none of the `git` commands seems to do the tricks you might have to get your hands dirty. Make a complete backup of your git repository and working folder to be sure, then venture with a flashlight into the `.git/refs/remotes` folder, then remove the remote folder you no longer want there. Afterwards, do a `git fsck` to be sure you didn't mess something else up. Also check the `.git/config` file for lingering traces of the remote.

Comment: Note that normally such remotes would have been removed with `git remote remove` in the first place, which would have taken care of the problem—presumably someone removed the remote "by hand" and failed to remove the corresponding remote-tracking branches "by hand".  The add-then-remove trick seems like the simplest cleanup though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion in the comments, this is what works:

```
git remote add <remote name> <url> 
git remote remove <remote name>
```

Seemed to clear out some dangling reference to the orphaned remote.

Comment: I did. Unfortunately same output.
`git remote remove staging`
`fatal: No such remote: staging`

Comment: Huh. Maybe just delete and re-clone then?

Comment: Another thought: can you `git remote add <name> <url>` and then `git remote remove <name>`? That might clean it up. Maybe `git gc` will detect the dangling reference, as well.

Comment: `git gc` did not do it. Going to try to your suggestion to add a new url and then remove.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Should the main answer be edited and I will accept the answer?

Comment: Actually it was @trejas who tried to do the edit, but made a typo himself, which I fixed in the edit approval process.

Comment: Thanks @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩

Answer (score 3):

[Is this the same question you have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-local-branches-no-longer-on-remote)

> `git remote prune origin` prunes tracking branches not on the remote.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like it should work in theory, but I did try this already (see the bottom part of my question). No dice.